# ConnectionError on connecting telethon with proxy

Tags: python, proxy, telethon

I am trying to connect the telethon client throw http-proxy and getting error.

> ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 1 time(s)

For testing purpose of my proxy I used this snippet code and it was successful.

```
import requests
proxies = {'http': 'http://XXX:YYY@p.webshare.io:20000',
       'https': 'http://XXX:YYY@p.webshare.io:20000'}
r = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org", proxies=proxies)
print(r.text)
```

And with telethon I am getting error:

```
proxy = (socks.HTTP, 'p.webshare.io', 20000, True, 'XXX', 'YYY')

with TelegramClient('anon', API_ID, API_HASH, proxy=proxy, connection_retries=1
                    ) as client:
```

Log:

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using proactor: IocpProactor
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.92:443/TcpFull...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 1 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 2...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 2 at connecting failed: TimeoutError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
raise ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed {} time(s)'.format(self._retries))
ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 1 time(s)
```

What is wrong with my code?

(Windows 10, python 3.8, telethon 1.13)

Comment: The default transport used by Telethon is not over HTTP, so a HTTP-only proxy won't work.

Comment: @Lonami you mean there is no way I can get connection with this proxy? Is there any workaround?

Comment: You may try using another `connection` when creating the client with [the HTTP one](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/network.html#telethon.network.connection.http.ConnectionHttp) although I have no idea if that will work because I haven't tried in forever and I don't personally care about proxies.